# TypeError: changeChecked is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, function, react-hooks, state

I am trying to pass changeChecked as prop from parent to this child component to capture the input element id but I am getting this error. I have mentioned the child component and parent component. Please help me to solve this error.

Child Component

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const CheckBox = ({ changeChecked, section }) => {


    return (
        <>
            {section.options.map((option, optionIdx) => (
                <div key={option.value} className="flex items-center">
                    <input
                        id={`filter-${section.id}-${optionIdx}`}
                        name={`${section.id}[]`}
                        defaultValue={option.value}
                        type="checkbox"
                        defaultChecked={option.checked}
                        onChange={() => changeChecked(option.id)}
                        className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 rounded text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                        
                    />
                    <label
                        htmlFor={`filter-${section.id}-${optionIdx}`}
                        className="ml-3 lg:text-sm min-w-0 flex-1 text-gray-500"
                    >
                        {option.label}
                    </label>
                </div>
            ))}
            
        </>
    )
}

export default CheckBox;
```

[image]

Parent Component

```
import CheckBox from "../pages/collections/checkbox"
export default function App() {


const filters = [
    {
        id: 'brand',
        name: 'Brands',
        options: [
            { value: 'Casio', label: 'Casio', checked: false },
            { value: 'Yamaha', label: 'Yamaha', checked: false },
        ],
    },
]

  const onChangeChecked = (id)=>{
    console.log(id)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
 {filters.map((section) => (
      <CheckBox section={section} changeChecked={onChangeChecked} />
 ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: try `const CheckBox = ( changeChecked, section ) => {`

Comment: No, it will not work because this method removes destructure of props and data will not be accessible.

Comment: try `const CheckBox = (props) => {`
and log props and see if you are receiving it

Comment: I only receive section prop. and error again is TypeError: props.changeChecked is not a function

Comment: I think share your parent component screen shot as well will help people solve your question.

Comment: I have shared it

Comment: @BigLoot Please see this `condesanbox` link based on your question: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-euclid-28xm18?file=/src/App.js
it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a full example of passing a function as a prop.

Don't forget to pass the props when you are using the Input component, or you will get the same error as above.

```
export default function App() {

  const onHandleClick = (e)=>{
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input  onHandleClick={onHandleClick}/>
    </div>
  );
}

function Input ({ onHandleClick }) {
  return <input onChange={(e) => onHandleClick(e)}/>
}
```

Comment: You can see I am also doing the same thing. But not working